# Why is this JavaScript for-loop not placing any innerHTML in the JavaScript generated div's

Tags: javascript, for-loop, split, innerhtml

I'm creating `<a href>`s which need to be split into two `<divs>`. Into this divs I need each character divided by a `<span>`. I had some success with creating the divs OR the spans for each character, but not both...

I created a Codepen which hopefully explains my problem a little bit better.

- The first result only shows the divs, but the spans are not showing
  up (don't get any error in my console.log).
- The hardcoded HTML below is the expected result.

I hope you guys can help me out. Let me know if you need more information.

```
<!-- HTML input: Not working -->
<a href='#' class='test' data-animation-type='letter-split'>Testword</a>

<!-- Expected result -->
<a href='#' class='test' data-animation-type='letter_split'>
  <div class='upper'>
    <span>T</span>
    <span>e</span>
    <span>s</span>
    <span>t</span>
    <span>w</span>
    <span>o</span>
    <span>r</span>
    <span>d</span>
  </div>
  <div class='down'>
    <span>T</span>
    <span>e</span>
    <span>s</span>
    <span>t</span>
    <span>w</span>
    <span>o</span>
    <span>r</span>
    <span>d</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

```
.test {
  color: orange;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: arial;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  .upper, .down {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 20px;
    background-color: green;
  }
}

.test {
  span {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```
function tryout() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-animation-type='letter-split']");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var string = elements[i].innerHTML;
    var length = string.length;
    string.split("");
    elements[i].innerHTML = "<span class='upper'></span><span class='down'></span>";
    var upper = elements[i].querySelector('.upper');
    var down = elements[i].querySelector('.down');
    for (var e; e < length; e++) {
      upper.innerHTML += "<span>" + string + "</span>";
      down.innerHTML += "<span>" + string + "</span>";
    }
  }
}
tryout();
```

The Codepen: 
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/iamFrankEU/pen/xxZwrad)

Comment: "I created a codepen".  Where?  Better yet, put the logic that is in your codepen *in your question*

Comment: Watch your formatting, if you try to write out HTML tags as raw text they get converted and don't show up. Also, you forgot to link to your Codepen, but site policy is that your code needs to be in the question itself and not an external link anyway.

Comment: Could you add your code to the question? It looks like you've forgotten to add a codepen link, but adding a code snippet straight to your question would be even better. Your question will probably be reopened to receive answers if you [edit] your question in this way.

Comment: [mcve] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: I'm sorry @Taplar, John Montgomery & Run_Script. The Codepen is added, just like my example code. Hope this question can be reopened.

Comment: `var e;` needs to be initialized to 0

Comment: Dear @Taplar, Thanks for your comment. At least it shows something now, but not the expected result. With the initialization of var e the for loop the entire word gets placed into the spans * the string length of the word (string 'tryout' is placed 6 times into a span. I want [t], [r], [y], [o], [u], [t], as spans. But thanks for your help.

Comment: That's because you're not grabbing a single character at a time.  You have the line `string.split("");` in your code, but you're not using it.  That line splits the string into an array, but it does not mutate the original variable.  You shouldn't need to do that and most likely can just use `string[e]`

Comment: Dear @Taplar, Thanks again for your message. I updated my Pen and it looks like it is working now! I don't know if this is the way you told me to, but I still want to thank you for your inspiration and time. I can go on now. Merci!